# Difference between 十几个人 and 几十个人

Tags: grammar

I read somewhere that in order to express "over a number of things/people" we can use this pattern:
(multiples of ten)+几+classifier+noun
like
十几个人:more than ten people (less than 20)
However, somewhere else I came across this pattern
几+十+classifier+noun
The sequence of 十 and 几 are exactly reversed in these two patterns.
I wonder if these two patterns have the same meaning or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

十 means 10, 几 means a few( less than 10 usually ). So 十几 means 10 + a few which indicates the number is 10+ but < 20. 几十 is a few of 10s so it is a multiple of 10, usually < 100 and definitely > 20.

Comment: 几十 >= 20 not > 20

Comment: @xenophōn but people will just say 20 when it is exactly 20 :)

Comment: Native Chinese goes for the idea that 几 is usually larger than 2, it is the same as *several*, you use it when you not sure or don't want to bother with the actual number, but one can always put a finger on it when the number is precisely 2.

Answer (score 8):

十几个人 = 10 <= x <= 19

几十个人 = x > 20

So the latter has more people.

Generally, the 几 in the word means that this number can be chosen arbitrarily from all numbers greater then 2, so 几百个人 is 200-999 people.

If you just want to express that there are a lot of people, then you usually put 几 in front to show there is more.

Comment: Feel like 几 usually indicates >= 2...

Comment: Yep, sorry my bad. (Actually I am a native Chinese, how on earth did I make that mistake??)

Answer (score 2):

My answer might not be how teachers would explain this typically, but here it is..

When you ask someone 這東西有幾個(几个)?, you can think of 幾(几) as a character that represents the uncertainty of counts.

So for "這東西有幾個", you can view it as "這東西有?個"

Same rule applies to your question:
幾十個 -> ?十個 -> **?0**, so it implies you have at least >19
十幾個 -> 十?個 -> **1?**, so it implies you have 11~19

幾百個 ->  **?00**,  implies you have at least >100
幾千個 -> **?000**, implies you have at least >1000

Same rule also applies when you want to answer:
五十幾個 -> **5?** -> 51~59
^ This however only makes sense if the count is under a hundred.
If more than a hundred, then we typically use 多:
五十多個 = **50+**
兩百多個 = **200**+
兩百幾個 would not make sense